# Django: return same data as PostListView in def post()

Tags: python, django

Is there a simple way for me to return the same data in post method using PostListView?

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       *create like in db*
       *flash message*
       return *same data as get request*
```

I have a simple Instagram replica app and this post list view shows all posts. Each posts has a like button. If a user clicks on this button it will create a new like object in db and will show a flash message. After that I want to show the same data as there were before clicking the button. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You would have to do some complex caching where you store the last posts that the user was looking at to do it like this. Even better would be to use Javascript to call a like creation view asynchronously so that the user doesn't have to load a new page

Comment: @IainShelvington The issue is that I do notk now JS at all however, as I already have an API for the like creation created I will try to google for some sample codes. Thanks!